# Mouse event firing but not performing function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple drawing program using a grid made of boxes with class `.box`. I want the boxes to gradually darken on each pass of the mouse by altering the opacity.

```
   $('.box').mouseenter(function() {
      var currentOp = parseInt($(this).css('opacity'));
      $(this).css('opacity', currrentOp + .1);
   });
```

The event fires once and changes the opacity from 0 to .1, but then won't continue to increase the opacity on subsequent mouse passes.

I'm able to get the desired results using this code:

```
   $('.box').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).css('opacity', '+=1');
   });
```

Could anyone tell me why my first attempt won't work? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gardnersj/us6bts2k/7/) is a JSFiddle with the whole code. Thanks!

Comment: i changed your code as `$('.box').mouseenter(function () {
        //var curOp = parseInt($(this).css('opacity'), 10);
        $(this).css('opacity', ''+$(this).css('opacity') + 0.1);
    });` and it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `parseInt()` is always **integer**, 0, in your case. You want to use `parseFloat()` instead.

Change:

```
var curOp = parseInt($(this).css('opacity'), 10);
```

To:

```
var curOp = parseFloat($(this).css('opacity'), 10);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/us6bts2k/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You use parseFloat, because if parseInt( 0.1 ) === 0

```
$('.box').mouseover(function () {
    var curOp = **parseFloat**($(this).css('opacity'), 10);
    $(this).css('opacity', curOp + 0.1);
});
```

;) (Y)